# Can we use GAEs with A3C asynchronous reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The Generalized Advantage Estimator seems very effective with algorithms like PPO in reinforcement learning. But most of the A3C algorithms I have seen use Averaged Advantage estimates. Is there any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can:

https://github.com/ikostrikov/pytorch-a3c

The reason is the GAE paper was released after A3C, so the paper implementation, which is what most people will look at, doesn't use GAE.

Relevant lines here: https://github.com/ikostrikov/pytorch-a3c/blob/master/train.py#L95-L98

Comment: Hi, sometimes when the rollout length of an A3C agent is low GAEs tends to make the training process unstable.